# How store data to array from json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, backbone.js

I have a json file in the format as follows:

```
{
  "recipe_type": [
    "vegetarian",
    "non-vegetarian"
  ],
  "recipe_times": [
    "<30min",
    "30-60min",
    "60-90min"
  ],
  "recipe_cuisines": [
    "arabian",
    "european",
    "Indian",
    "chinese"
  ]
}
```

I need to store each list to separate array:

```
@recipe = new JS.M.Recipe()
@recipe.fetch(@recipe.getRecipeType())
@recipeTypes = @recipe.getRecipeType()//Here data is getting as objetcs..if i use alert to print this. It showing output like "[object Object]"..
```

I want to store data as follows:

```
@recipe_type = @recipeTypes.get("recipe_type")
@recipe_times = @recipeTypes.get("recipe_times")//This is wrong
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using backbone then you must be having underscorejs loaded on the page. If yes, this should work for you 
`lists = _.values(data)` 
where data is the JSON object mentioned above.